# Showing Polygon Map With Dynamic Path On VueJS

Tags: google-maps, vue.js

I got some trouble about implementing google map in vuejs. I was create polygon component like this:

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "MapPolygon",
        props: {
            google: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
            map: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
            paths: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            const { Polygon } = this.google.maps;

            new Polygon({
                paths: this.paths,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 3,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map: this.map,
            });
        },

        render() {}
    }
</script>
```

then when i click some data the polygon can't show on the map. This is my code:

```
    <template>
             <map-loader :map-config="mapConfig">
                  <template slot-scope="{google, map}">
                        <map-polygon
                             :google="google"
                             :map="map"
                             :paths="zone">
                        </map-polygon>
                  </template>
             </map-loader>
    </template>

    <script>
    import MapLoader from "../../../components/maps/MapLoader";
    import MapPolygon from "../../../components/maps/MapPolygon";

    export default {
        name: "PolaRuang",
        components: {MapPolygon, MapLoader},
        data() {
            return {
                zone: [],
            }
        },

        computed: {
            mapConfig() {
                return {
                    ...mapSettings
                }
            },
        },

        methods: {
            getMap(polaRuangId){
                this.spinner = true;
                axios.post(`/truang/service/pola/showPolaRuang/${polaRuangId}`)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.zonaRuang = response.data;
                        this.spinner = false;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        this.spinner = false;
                        this.$toasted.global.error(error.response.data);
                    })
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

if i set the zone data static, the polygon show on the map, but when i set dynamic the polygon can't show. Could anyone here to help me to fixing this problem?
Thank You!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but can you show me the code that adds the paths dynamically. Are you by chance using this.paths.push(newPt)?

Comment: thank @xsoftie for your attention, but the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved
i am adding the watch function for watching the `newPath` inside the polygon components. So, this is the code :

```
    <script>
    export default {
        name: "MapPolygon",
        props: {
            google: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
            map: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
            paths: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            }
        },

        watch: {
             async paths (newPaths) {
                const { Polygon } = this.google.maps;

                let polygon = new Polygon({
                    paths: newPaths,
                    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 3,
                    fillColor: '#FF0000',
                    fillOpacity: 0.35,

                });
                polygon.setMap(this.map);
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            const { Polygon } = this.google.maps;

            new Polygon({
                paths: this.paths,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 3,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map: this.map,
            });
        },

        render() {}
    }
</script>
```